# Lambda .Where limitation to string

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this method:

```
public List<object> GetThings(List<Guid> listOfGuids)
{
    var query = serviceContext.Xrm.crmEntity;
    bool anyTypeOfSearch = false; // use this to know if we have actually applied any search criteria.

    if(listOfGuids != null && listOfGuids.Count > 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => listOfGuids.Contains(x.lgc_muncipalityid.Id));
        anyTypeOfSearch = true;
    }

    var result = new List<object>();
    if(anyTypeOfSearch) // instead of a variable here, can i check if there are any whereconditions applied to the query?
        result = query
            .Select(x => new SupplierSearchResultModel()
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.lgc_name,
            })
            .ToList();

    LogMessage("GetThings.Query", <insert code to get query.Where condition tostring()>);

    return result;
}
```

In the real code there are several different if structures with `.Where` conditions in them and sometimes a call can reach this code without any parameters. In this case I don't want to run the query as the result set would be huge. So I only want to run the query if at least once the `.Where()` condition has been applied.

Now my question is, can I check a lambda query variable for if it has any `.Where()` conditions applied without using an external bool like I am?

An alternate interesting usage point would be if there is some way to get some sort of `query.Where().ToString()` method that would show what conditions will be applied which could be logged in case of errors...

Comment: Usually you whould limit the results of your query using `.Take()` regardless of the query itself.

Comment: I would too, but as the client can sort the data by the column of their choosing I would never know If I am removing one of their first rows or last without doing the query all over for every sorting. So I instead choose a slightly slower first search for the benefit of a more usable result.

Comment: yup had the same issue regarding sorting. Managed to get sorting working serverside using QueryExpression. But sorting by attributes on joined tables was not supported (crm2011) it seemed. Sadly had to do sorting after querying. Linq2Crm provider misses a lot of power we are used to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick & dirty, if you don't care about having a pretty result:

```
LogMessage(query.Expression.ToString());
```

But it will not show you the content of your array parameter, though.

**edit** Better solutions:

1) What you are looking for is an expression visitor. A template for what you [want to do here](https://gist.github.com/oguimbal/507f1a6e35981dddc50227970b388449), which should then be used like:

```
LogMessage(query.ToPrettyString());
```

2) Think about an expression `query.Where(x=>x.member == GetSomething())` do you want it to be printed like that ? Or do you want `GetSomething()` result to appear as a string result ? If the second solution, then that's something you can do [with this](https://gist.github.com/oguimbal/5e726c00881b2feb7ec10ba998b9b9c2)

Comment: Ah, I'll have to expriment with that. Any alternatives if I want paramaters?
Pretty would be nice but no really neccessary.. :)

Comment: Yes, there are, but they require a bit of computation since it requires to traverse the expression tree, and evaluate each constant node (it's not completely neutral in terms of performances, even if its negligible compared to a network call)

Comment: i could find you a sample if you wish

Comment: That would be greatly appreciated, or just a link if you found a place where I can read about it!

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own implementation of the [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor(v=vs.110).aspx) to traverse the nodes of the expression. You can do something like this:

```
public class WhereVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private static bool _filter;
    private static WhereVisitor _visitor = new WhereVisitor();

    private WhereVisitor() { }

    public new static bool Visit(Expression expression)
    {
        _filter = false;
        //Cast to ExpressionVisitor to use the default Visit and not our new one
        ((ExpressionVisitor)_visitor).Visit(expression);
        return _filter;
    }
    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Method.Name == "Where")
            _filter = true;
        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
bool containsWhere = WhereVisitor.Visit(query.Expression);
```

If you want you can of course expand the visitor to save the expressions that contain a `Where` clause, but this one will just tell you if there are is `Where` or not.